# How to show audio files to client using nodejs and angularjs?

Tags: angularjs, node.js, express

I am able to upload my `wav` files and converted `mp3` files using *ffmpeg* converter, that converts `wav` files to `mp3`, in a "uploads" folder - but I am unable to show them on browser.

I am using `AngularJS` and `Node.js` and I am new on these technologies.

I want to show all the files on browser instead of uploading to the uploads folder.

Comment: This is way to broad for a reasonable answer.

Answer (score 0):

If you're using express you could mount your uploads folder as a file serving directory and users could download the MP3s via a link

```
app.use(express.static('path/to/uploads'));
```

(from http://expressjs.com/en/starter/static-files.html)